# Use HelloSign for e-signature in Angular project and how?

Tags: node.js, angular, hellosign-api

I am starting new project with Angular and node.js API. It has one functionality of document signing with e-signature.
I am not sure if I can use HelloSign with angular or not. And How?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question is regardless of any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are able to instantiate the HelloSign embedded client on your frontend code and make a call to client.open() you should not have an issue using Angular JS. Here's a link for the [Sign Embedded Library](https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-embedded/wiki/API-Documentation-(v2)) and the [CDN Links](https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-embedded/wiki/CDN-Links)